# converting no standard date like 1-01 (year-month) to int or standard data in order to use for sci_kit learn

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

I need to convert this kind of Year variable in  Panda

```
 Year  Sales
0   1-01  266.0
1   1-02  145.9
2   1-03  183.1
3   1-04  119.3
4   1-05  180.3
5   1-06  168.5
6   1-07  231.8
7   1-08  224.5
8   1-09  192.8
9   1-10  122.9
10  1-11  336.5
11  1-12  185.9
12  2-01  194.3
13  2-02  149.5
14  2-03  210.1
15  2-04  273.3
16  2-05  191.4
17  2-06  287.0
18  2-07  226.0
19  2-08  303.6
20  2-09  289.9
21  2-10  421.6
22  2-11  264.5
23  2-12  342.3
24  3-01  339.7
25  3-02  440.4
26  3-03  315.9
27  3-04  439.3
```

in oder to use it for sci kit learn or others methods to predict, I do not know how should i do it, as it has nonstandard format of date

i used

```
pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%m-%d')
```

but It does not work, 
can you tell what would be your approach

bests

Comment: Does the first digit of each entry represent a year? If so, what year does '1' represent?

Comment: it means only first year, for instance 3-01 mean third year first month, i took one day...i would really appricate any help ...thanks

Comment: Year  Sales
0   1-01  266.0
1   1-02  145.9
2   1-03  183.1
3   1-04  119.3
4   1-05  180.3
5   1-06  168.5
6   1-07  231.8
7   1-08  224.5
8   1-09  192.8
9   1-10  122.9
10  1-11  336.5
11  1-12  185.9
12  2-01  194.3
13  2-02  149.5
14  2-03  210.1
15  2-04  273.3
16  2-05  191.4
17  2-06  287.0
18  2-07  226.0
19  2-08  303.6
20  2-09  289.9
21  2-10  421.6
22  2-11  264.5
23  2-12  342.3
24  3-01  339.7
25  3-02  440.4
26  3-03  315.9
27  3-04  439.3